# Using IP Addresses in my application's configuration

Tags: configuration, network-programming, ip, hostname

For many years we have been using IP addresses (so-called dotted quads) in our configuration database to identify remote hosts.

We have one new developer who insists that we should use names and not numbers to connect to proceses on remote machines.

This sounds alright *in theory* by not all names will resolve between geographic regions in our company. I am also concerned that while it may seem to work in a development or QA environment (as he has shown me) the whole thing will blow up in production and we'll be caught with our pants down when the explosion happens.

How can I convince him that IP addresses are better than hostnames?

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on the deployment environment. You better support ***both***.

#### Edit:

You sir are not listening to what other people are trying to say. It looks like you already made up your mind before asking the question and now you are just looking for support of *your* opinion. Sorry, it doesn't work like this here.

Comment: Why should we support both? IPs are working. Deployment environment is Solaris x86. Also, what if the deployment environment doesn't support both?

Comment: To be able to deploy with or without DNS. Same as your browser - it'll work with IP address and with a hostname.

Comment: My browser doesn't resolve all internal names. Should I log a bug with Internet Explorer?

Comment: Exactly - that's why it supports *both* IP addresses *and* hostnames.

Comment: Suppose that my application *does* support both. The environment still may not. This is why it is better to be consistent and use IP addresses. Which brings me back to my original question: How do I convince my developer not to use names in our configuration?

Answer (score 1):

(Homework?)

I'm surprised "the explosion" didn't happen yet.

Use DNS/hostnames because...

- ... you can change the target IP of a hostname for all clients in the network in the blink of an eye
- ... hostnames are easier to remember (for humans)
- ... IP addresses might change; especially if you are using "public" IP addresses
- ... you don't have to re-compile code if a hostname changes (or fix configuration files)

Please learn a bit about basic DNS (Domain Name Server) techniques first.

You might want a local DNS server (next to the gateway/router) on each regional location and a "central" name server (possibly hosted by a professional hosting provider).

Comment: Not homework. We are using only internal 10.*.*.* addresses that will not change and they are easy to remember.

Comment: We would have to update the config DB if a hostname changes. IP addresses do not change. That is a good argument in my favor.

Comment: Yeah, but the whole idea of hostnames is to "detach" the dynamic nature of IP addresses from the static nature of memories (user's brains, source code, etc.) from each other. Using hostnames you just put in "server1.intern.mydomain.com" and if something changes, just update the DNS server and voila.

Comment: So basically if your IP addresses never, ever change there is probably no big point in replacing them with hostnames. But I had a few, let's say, not so nice situations in the past 10 years where I was in a similar situation to yours and denied using hostnames. Just do it. It's less work to set up DNS than fixing broken crap later on.

Answer (score 0):

Your dotted quads aren't going to be particularly useful when IPv6 is deployed.

Comment: This is not an answer and deserves a down vote. Also we are not going to use IPv6 addresses internally so it's not even relevant!

Comment: @Ariel I think it is an answer. Aaron is arguing that hostnames will work with both IPv4 and IPv6, while IPv4 addresses can limit you in the future. Are you 100% sure you will not be using IPv6 ever?